# PixelSearch not working

Tags: syntax, autohotkey

I am trying to use PixelSearch to just click a green button (shown below) in Windows 7 x64, but it it not working as I expect it to:

```
#IfWinActive ahk_exe chrome.exe  
    $^Enter::
    $^NumpadEnter::

    PixelSearch, x, y, 652, 1040, 1000,1050 , 0x7BDF18, 10, Fast
    if ErrorLevel,
        return
    else
        Click,%x%,%y%
    Return
#IfWinActive
```

The size of the button changes, hence the great difference between x1 and x2.
PixelSearch returns only (652, 1040) as the valid coordinate no matter what threshold I set it.

What I am I doing wrong here?

[image: Green button]

Comment: What kind of window are you working with? Browser, some kind of GUI? Also, please provide an image in a lossless format (e.g. bmp).

Comment: Sorry about that. I really need to make a mental note to write out the details when asking a question. I have updated the question accordingly. Windows 7, Google Chrome. May I ask why you asked for bmp?

Comment: So I assume it's a website. Which one is it? By the way, PNG isn't lossless either. You can't accurately analyze compressed screenshots...

Comment: Yes it is a website. codeacademy.com. It is not a picture, but a button with color generated by CSS. Here is a sample [page](http://www.codecademy.com/courses/web-beginner-en-HZA3b/0/1?curriculum_id=50579fb998b470000202dc8b) from the website. You can see the button in question after clicking on blue button on the bottom: 'Save & Submit Code`

Comment: AHK isn't very well suited for such tasks. It doesn't need to be, since there are much more powerful tools to automate browser interaction. Take a look at [Tampermonkey](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tampermonkey/dhdgffkkebhmkfjojejmpbldmpobfkfo) for instance. You'll need to know a little JavaScript, but handling websites with userscripts is much easier and efficient.

Comment: Could you please explain why it is not well suited as an answer? So I can accept it. I have used Tampermonkey and also iMacros, but I wanted this feature to work with AHK because it is much more versatile and could work across different applications. I am sadden by this shortcoming.